# The depth of left subtree less than the depth of right subtree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I need algorithm that check for every nods in a binary tree if the depth of left subtree less than the depth of right subtree, return true or false.
it must be in O(n).

I think to build a function that calculate the depth for every subtree and use it to check for every nodes if the depth of left subtree less than the depth of right subtree, but i think this will be O(n^2).

Comment: You can solve it through the recursive implementation of dfs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww Can you point to some specific text on [the scope page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) that deems this off topic? It's not a very detailed question, but it describes a specific programming problem, suggests a solution, and recognises that the solution isn't good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Right: that would end up O(n^2). You need to do this by depth first search. Write a function that determines the depth of the subtree rooted at node `n`. It takes a node, asks (recursively) for the depth of the left subtree, and the depth of the right subtree. Return a pair `(int, boolean)` where the `int` is the maximum of the two subtree depths, and the `boolean` is `true` if the left one is smaller and `false` if not.

Now you just invoke this on your root node. It will recursively calculate depth and balance information on every node of the tree.

You can do it without returning a pair, as in u_seem_surprised's solution, if you can alter the nodes and put in a field that you can use to annotate each one with the answer. But either way, it's now O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Recursive dfs solution :

```
struct node{
    int val;
    bool leftGreater;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

int solve(Node *n){
    if(n == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    int left = solve(n->left) + 1;
    int right = solve(n->right) + 1;
    if(left > right){
        n->leftGreater = true;
    }else{
        n->leftGreater = false;
    }
return max(left, right);
}
```